# Rebase values in an array to match the chart scale

Tags: c#, array

I have 2 `long[24]` arrays. Both of them contain values for each hour of a day. One of them has hit count and other queue times. Now queue times in ms are 5 digit numbers, counts are 2 digit numbers. I want to show them in one chart, because queue times are to some degree corresponding with hits, but the scale is totally different. So what I came up with is that I take the max value from one list and recalculate all the values from second array using that maximum.

```
var count = new long[24]; // values similar to [0, 9, 25, 65 ..]
var waitings = new long[24]; // values similar to [34111, 65321, 5003 ..]
count = NormalizeDataset(count, waitings.Max()); 
// ... skipped
@functions {

    private long[] NormalizeDataset(long[] count, long max)
    {
        long countMax = count.Max();
        var returnable = new long[24];
        for (int i = 0; i < count.Length; i++)
        {
            var l = (count[i] * max) / countMax;
            returnable[i] = l;

        }
        return returnable;
    }

}
```

Does doing it like this make sense? How is this problem usually solved?

Comment: This problem is usually solved by using a chart with multiple y-Axis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though there is not much code to review a few remarks:

1. `returnable` has a hard coded length. Should your input array ever need to be larger you'd have to remember to make this larger as well. A simple

   ```
   var returnable = new long[count.Length];
   ```

   would eliminate any need to worry about this ever again.
2. Given the current data constraints it's not really a problem but multiplying by `max` first could yield in an overflow. It might pay off to store the scaling factor as double instead (in which case it can also be pre-calculated).
3. Using LINQ would make the code a bit bit more concise.

---

Refactored method:

```
private long[] NormalizeDataset(long[] count, long max)
{
    double scale = max / (double)count.Max();
    return count.Select(x => x * scale).ToArray();
}
```

Given that `scale` is probably around the order of `100` and that the scaling is more or less an arbitrary choice you could just not use `double` for the `scale`.